# How to zero-out the whole array of structure objects which contains other structures and arrays?

Tags: c++

How to zero-out the whole array of structure objects which contains other structures, arrays, etc in the more standard way?

In my case it's an object of `INPUT` structure.

Is the following code do it right?

```
INPUT newline_input[4] = {0};
```

Or should I use something like `std::memset`?

Thanks in advance.

Definition of [INPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It depends on what INPUT is, usually you use the constructor to set the object to a well defined state.

Comment: @Surt http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If INPUT is a class with default constructor, you don't need any `=`

Comment: @NeilKirk In C++11.  But it's perfectly legal to use the `=` here, and will work in earlier versions of C++ as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah to clarify what I mean, If INPUT is a class with default constructor, then you don't need any `= {..};`

Comment: @NeilKirk, but it doesn't (as far down the documentation I went) so it will use the trivial default constructor which does nothing leaving it undefined if it is constructed on the stack. And only accidentally correctly (zero) initialized if defined on heap.

Comment: @NeilKirk Aha.  Yes; if you have correctly written classes, they "auto-initialize" systematically.

Comment: @Surt There's no explanation in the question what is INPUT is, it could be anything. But yes, my comment missed the caveat - it requires a default construct that sets it up appropriately.

Comment: @NeilKirk he does say that it contains "other structures, arrays, etc.", which suggests POD to me.  (If it's not a POD, it should have a constructor, in which case, `= {0}` is likely not to compile.)

Comment: Added link to definition of INPUT which @FrozenHeart gave in comment 2.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work, even better is this:

```
INPUT newline_input[4] = {};
```

Comment: Because it does not require that the first element be constructible from 0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see only the first element of the first array element would be set to the value, so only because it is set to zero here would it be correct. If it had been '= {1}' and you expected all elements to be 1, it would fail as the elements would be {1,0,0,0 ... etc. }

I don't like the '=' because it looks like it would call an assignment operator (which is irrelevant for this structure but may be a problem in other cases).

If the array was a global its memory would be zeroed but that is accidental that the wanted values are zero. If the array was on the stack random values (whatever is on the stack) would populate the array.

Initialization in the age of C++14 its a bit more complicated.

```
INPUT newline_input[4] {}; // empty value initialization
```

So use empty [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) for your data which include a `union` syntax 4 is used

```
T object {};
```

and then effect 3 followed by 2(C++14)

```
3) If T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized
2) If T is a class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor (that is, it may be a class with a defaulted default constructor or with an implicitly-defined one) then the object is zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor   (since C++14)
```

Which should then call [zero-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

These unions with unknown content is a problem when they are provided without constructors as the programmer would have to know how to put them into a well defined state.

Using list initialization looks too much like assignment and

```
INPUT newline_input[4] = {0};
or
INPUT newline_input[4] = {};
```

It will use syntax 10 in [List initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) followed by [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) as INPUT is an array/struct/union. And since the number of initializer clauses is less than the array length, this effect will be used

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of
>   members or initializer clauses is completely empty, the remaining
>   members are initialized by their brace-or-equal initializers, if
>   provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) by empty
>   lists, which performs value-initialization. If a member of a reference
>   type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed
>   (references cannot be value-initialized)

But members of the standard comity has moved away from this form [link to where Bjarne S. says so] to the value initializing.

Comment: `T a[n] = {..};` does not call the assignment operator.

Comment: I don't follow the "age of C++14" stuff.  He strongly suggests that his class is a PODS; in this case, except for an additional syntax, C++11/C++14 change nothing.

Comment: Hi @JamesKanze, trying to wrap my mind around all the terms in the standard and when they are used correctly, could you point out where I chose the wrong path in my general reasoning (excluding the specific case of setting INPUT to zero).

Comment: Initialization is covered in section 8.5.  There were no significant changes in the wording of this section between C++03 and C++11.  The section was reworked between C++98 and C++03, but this was because it was felt that the wording in C++98 didn't correctly express what was intended; the _intent_ hasn't changes since pre-standard days.  C++11 does introduce a new syntax, but for most types (those which don't have a `std::list_initializer` constructor), even the new syntax doesn't change that much.

Comment: @JamesKanze, so [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) is wrong? 'Otherwise, the object is zero-initialized (until C++11) Otherwise, nothing is done. (since C++11)'?

Comment: @Surt Hmm.  The wording is different between the two, but the end effect is identical.  (Default initialization does include zero initialization in C++11, but the standard goes on to change default initialization to no initialization in all of the cases where this would have made a difference.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62186/discussion-between-surt-and-james-kanze).

Comment: @Surt before C++11, the concept of "default initialization" did not apply to POD types at all, as cppreference points at in text and again in a note at the bottom... I reworded to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @JamesKanze, removed the pre-C++11 comment.